# Can't send data to Firebase Realtime Database on Android

Tags: android, firebase, time, firebase-realtime-database, synchronization

Everything works fine (data is sent to firebase and I can see it in console) until I change system time on android device (I manually set incorrect time). When I do this, firebase stops sending data to firebase realtime database, and starts again if I correct the time.
Couldn't find anything related in the Internet, read firebase documentation one more time, but found nothing useful. 
Version of firebase I'm using is 11.8.0. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There must be Some exception . Check error logs . usually Bad timestamp exception thrown with xmpp .

Comment: @ADM thanx for pointing the correct way. I figured out what's the problem was. Problem was that I changed system time too way back, so the system certificates become invalid and prevented network connections.

Comment: Yeah That's the spirit . Bravo..